# operator[] on basic types with pointer argument

Tags: c++

What happening in following code?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 37;
    int* pi = &i;
    i[pi];  //works
    i[0];   //error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
}
```

Why is allowed to indexing int with pointer argument and what does it do?

Comment: `i[pi]` is the same as `pi[i]` is the same as `*(pi + i)`

Comment: in C++, array indexing is explicitly implemented using (commutative) pointer arithmetic (along the lines of `*(pi + i)`) and it was left so that `pi[i]` and `i[pi]` behaved the same. in the second case, writing `i[reinterpret_cast<int *>(0)]` would do as you expected, i.e. undefined behavior as it dereferences a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

`i[pi]` is the same as `*(i + pi)`.